# Check if array contains text from a list and when a value apears more then once display that value

Tags: excel-formula

What if I have 4 columns with data, and want the value that is more than once in those 4 columns(A-B-C-D).

```
apple  pear  melon  grape
melon  apple melon  grape
pear   melon melon  pear

My list in column E is;

``
apple
pear
melon
grape

And what I would like is that in column F the value appears of the fruit that is more than once in a row. 
So F1 should return nothing, F2 should return "melon", and F3 should return "pear, melon"

Is that posible with a formula?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

In `B1`, array ("Ctrl"+Shift"+"Enter") formula copied down :

```
=MID(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<a>A<b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","a|a/b[not(preceding::* =.)][following::* =.]")),4,999)
```

Remark : If you have Office 365, the above formula is normal entry.

[image]

If source data put in separated cells, then formula become >>

In `F1`, array ("Ctrl"+Shift"+"Enter") formula copied down :

```
=MID(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<a>A<b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,A1:D1)&"</b></a>","a|a/b[not(preceding::* =.)][following::* =.]")),4,999)
```

Remark : If you have Office 365, the above formula is also normal entry.

[image]

Comment: Thanks,
But in your example you put the fruits in one cell.
And I have 4 columns with the fruits.
So in A1 the value is apple, B1 is pear, C1 melon, etc.
Is that posible?

Comment: @Marc, please see my post new edit.